# How to add sorting for field object of graphql type which refers to different graphql type?

Tags: neo4j, graphql

I am using Neo4j dB and using pattern comprehension to return the values. I have 2 types Person and Friend:
 (p:Person)-[:FRIEND_WITH]->(f:Friend)

```
Type Person{
  id: String
  name: String
  friends: [Friend]
}

 Type Friend{
  id: String
  name: String

}   

 type Query {
    persons( limit:Int = 10): [Person]
    friends( limit:Int = 10): [Friend]
  }
```

What i want to do is to pull the array list of field **friends** (present in Person Type) in ascending order when the "persons" query executes. For e.g.

```
  {
  "data": {
   "persons": {
     "id": "1",
     "name": "Timothy",
     "friends": [
       {
        "id": "c3ef473",
        "name": "Adam",     
       },
       {
        "id": "ef4e373",
        "name": "Bryan",     
       }, 
       (  
        "id": "e373ln45",
        "name": "Craig",     
       },
```

How should I do it ? I researched regarding the sorting, but I did not find anything specific on the array object's sorting when we are using pattern comprehension in neo4j. Any suggestions would be really helpful !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the [sortBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#sortBy) function of lodash to return the result into an ascending order. 
And here is the graphql resolver query:

```
    persons(_, params) {
       let query = `MATCH (p:Person)
                    RETURN p{
                   .id,
                   .name,
                   friends: [(p)-[:FRIEND_WITH]->(f:Friend)) | f{.*}]
                   }

                   LIMIT $limit;`;

      return dbSession().run(query, params)
     .then(result => {
       return result.records.map(record => {
         let item = record.get("p");
             item.friends = sortBy(item.friends, [function(i) {
             return i.name;
        }]);
          return item;
      })
    })
}
```